# How to encrypt a binary executable and ask to enter the password before running the binary on Mac

Tags: encryption, executable, password-protection

You compile your program into a binary executable, and you want to protect it before you send it to someone. Even better, make the executable runnable only within a certain period of time with the password -- when the time period expires, the program can no longer be run. How can you achieve such goals?

I've read some posts on this forum, the closest is to hard wire the password inside your source code and do a comparison when the program is run. However, I don't think this is secure especially when your source code is in perl or java.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try to zip  the execute file so that when user try to run it can ask for password thaen run it ..  and for timing option you can add the time checking into the main executable file ..

Comment: Yeah, that works for something. But after a user unzip the product, he can pass it to anyone else without a password. Adding time checking into the main executable can be easily circumvented by changing the system clock.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using the [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module), there is no secure solution. Both the password and the time check can be bypassed by modifying the program to not perform the checks at all. You can only utilize obscurity, meaning you can only raise the bar for the amount of effort needed to bypass your measures.

Comment: Is there a good TPM solution, then? I know you can buy a dongle and a piece of software product to implement the time check and password verification, but you'll have to buy a dongle. I am wondering if there is a free solution without a dongle. BTW, which TPM product would you recommend? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of anything that uses TPM